# Load a picture from one inserted ActiveX Image to another - VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pictures

I got a set of named pictures on an Excel sheet, created by the "Insert" button in development tag, and from the section "ActiveX controls" from the "Insert" button. What I want is, when I click on one of the images of the set I have, to load the picture the clicked image holds to another, specific Image I have in a certain place for that purpose. How shall that be done with VBA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. I just need to do, etc if I want to copy from Image1 to Image2,

```
Image1.Picture = Image2.Picture.
```